# Execute task 4 times in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am using Azure Pipelines to deploy an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application to Azure.

I am successfuly deploying to ONE machine using the following Azure Pipeline jobs:

```
variables:
  azureSubscription: 'Azure'
  buildConfiguration: ’Staging’


- stage: Publish Staging
  dependsOn: Test
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration ‘$(buildConfiguration)’ --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: Api
      inputs:
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApi.zip'
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: 'Web App on Linux'
        webAppName: ‘myapi'
```

However I need to deploy to 4 machines and what changes in each deployment is:

azureSubscription: 'Azure'
  buildConfiguration: ’Staging’

Do I need to replicate my code 4 times or is there a way to accomplish this?

I mean, to run the code 4 times each with different variable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set variable at the job level to make it available only to a specific job. We can also deploy with multiple stages, just set variable at the stage level.(Refer to [Set variables in pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline) for details).

So, for example, you can add 4 jobs to deploy to 4 machines such like below:

```
- stage: Publish Staging
  dependsOn: Test
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    variables:
      azureSubscription: 'Azure1'
      buildConfiguration: ’Staging1’
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration ‘$(buildConfiguration)’ --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: Api
      inputs:
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApi.zip'
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: 'Web App on Linux'
        webAppName: ‘myapi'

  - job: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    variables:
      azureSubscription: 'Azure2'
      buildConfiguration: ’Staging2’
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration ‘$(buildConfiguration)’ --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: Api
      inputs:
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApi.zip'
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: 'Web App on Linux'
        webAppName: ‘myapi'     

  - job: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    variables:
      azureSubscription: 'Azure2'
      buildConfiguration: ’Staging3’
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration ‘$(buildConfiguration)’ --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: Api
      inputs:
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApi.zip'
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: 'Web App on Linux'
        webAppName: ‘myapi'     

  - job: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    variables:
      azureSubscription: 'Azure4'
      buildConfiguration: ’Staging4’
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration ‘$(buildConfiguration)’ --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: Api
      inputs:
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApi.zip'
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: 'Web App on Linux'
        webAppName: ‘myapi'
```

Comment: @MiguelMoura Have you resolved the issue by the answer? Any update?